# Python string formatting fill value as variable

Tags: python-2.7, string-formatting

So I have this simple `print` statement:

```
print "%-10s %s" % ("test","string")
```

which prints the desired output:

```
test       string
```

I'm trying to figure out the correct syntax for a case where the fill value is a variable. Example:

```
w = 10
print "%-s %s" % (w,"test","string")
```

So `%-s` should be replaced with what to accommodate the fill value?

If I remember it correctly, the syntax is similar to `%-xs` where `x` is replaced by a an int variable. I might be mistaken though.

#### Note

I know this question is probably duplicated since this is really elementary string formatting issue. However, after some time of searching for the right syntax I gave up.

Comment: What output are you trying to achieve?

Comment: 10x. Updated my question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would be inclined to use [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format), instead:

```
>>> print "{:{width}}{}".format("test", "string", width=10)
test      string
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this in two stages: First, create the proper format string, then use it to create the actual output. Use `%d` as a placeholder for the width and escape each other `%` as `%%`.

```
formatstring = "%%-%ds %%s" % w
print formatstring % ("test","string")
```

Or in one line:

```
print ("%%-%ds %%s" % w) % ("test","string")
```

---

*Update:* As pointed out by Martijn in the comments, you can also [use `*` in the format string](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting):

```
print "%-*s %s" % (w,"test","string")
```

From the documentation:

> Minimum field width (optional). If specified as an '*' (asterisk), the actual width is read from the next element of the tuple in values, and the object to convert comes after the minimum field width and optional precision.

Comment: This is overkill. Even the old string formatting format allows for dynamically set widths; The `*` in `'%-*s %s' % (w, 'test', 'string')` takes `w` for the width.

Comment: @MartijnPieters great job. `'%-*s` is exactly the syntax I've been trying so hard to remember.